# Meaning - norm about the norm

Tags: meaning, legalese

> If you help the norms along by praising people who are generous
>   and condemning the litterbug, you contribute to the maintenance
>   of an ethic; the rest of us benefit, and we don’t compensate you—and
>   you probably don’t get any tangible benefits yourself from delivering the
>   scolding. Why, then, would you do it? Because there’s a **norm about the
>   norm**: you feel good about enforcing it.

Source: p 115, The Legal Analyst, Ward Farnsworth

I'm guessing that [Definition 1.2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/norm) applies to the first bolded 'norm', but which definition for the 2nd **norm**? Also, does this entire phrase mean " 'a required standard' about 'a required standard' "? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these uses of norm are using a variation on definition 1.1: "Something that is usual, typical, or standard", not 1.2.  The variation is that this "norm" is an ideal -- something that most people in society want to be usual, typical, or standard -- that most people don't live up to all the time, and some people never live up to.

The first two examples of norms are "(people should) be generous" and "don't litter".

The third example of a norm is "(people should) encourage other people to live up to (society's) norms".

Answer (score 0):

There's a [meaning of *norm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(social)) not really covered by those definitions. A norm can be a social expectation, requirement or rule.

In your example, there's a norm that people aren't supposed to litter. But there's a further norm that's about the first one: if they do litter, you're supposed to scold them, and should feel good about doing so.